# Rebol 3: reading STDIN efficiently line by line (to make awk like tool)

Tags: stdin, rebol, rebol3

I am trying to make an **awk** like tool that uses Rebol 3 to process bigger text files with bash pipes and tools. I am having a problem reading STDIN line by line in Rebol 3?

For example this shell command produces 3 lines:

```
$ (echo "first line" ; echo "second line" ; echo "third line" )
first line
second line
third line
```

But the Rebol's **input** word reads all 3 lines at the same time. I would expect it to stop at newline as it stops if you use input interactively.

```
r3 --do 'while [ x: input ] [ if empty? x [ break ] print x print   "***" ]' 
abcdef
abcdef
***
blabla
blabla
***
```

But when I run it all together it reads whole input at once. I could read it all at once and split into lines, but I want it to work in a "streaming" manner as I usually *cat* in many 1000-s of lines.

```
$ (echo "first line" ; echo "second line" ; echo "third line" )  \
  | r3 --do 'while [ x: input ] [ if empty? x [ break ] print x print "***" ]' 
first linesecond linethird line
***
```

I also looked at source of *input* to make a similar function. I could read in character per character in a *while* loop and check for *newlines* but that doesn't seem efficient.

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out and it seems to work well even on big, 10000 lines files. It's could be written more elegantly and improved though.

The function **r3awk** takes *STDIN* and a block of code that it executes per line, binding line variable to it:

```
r3awk: func [ code /local a lines line partial ] [ 
    partial: copy ""
    lines: read/lines/string system/ports/input
    while [ not empty? lines ] [
        lines/1: rejoin [ partial lines/1 ]
        partial: pull lines
        foreach line lines [
            do bind code 'line
        ] 
        if error? try [ lines: read/lines/string system/ports/input ] [ lines: copy [] ]
    ]
    line: partial
    do bind code 'line
]
```

It works like this. **read/lines** reads a number of characters from the stream and returns a block of lines. Each time it's called it reads a next batch of characters like this, so it's all wrapped in a while loop. The code processes (do-es the code block) as the while loops (not at the end).

The batch of characters doesn't end on newline so last line is **partial**  each time. And so is the first line in the next batch, hence it joins them together. At the end it has to process the last (this time non-partial) line. **Try** is there because some lines caused utf encoding errors.

It can be used like this in command line:

```
(echo "first line" ; echo "second line" ; echo "third line" ) | \
 r3 --import utils.r --do 'r3awk [ parse line [ copy x to space (print x) ] ]'
first
second
third
```

Things to improve: make function generally better, deduplicate some code. Check what happens if the read/lines does end exactly on the newline.

Comment: Good find about `read/lines` buffering on STDIN.  However it doesn't fully work for me on MacOS (OSX) :(    Instead of a `block!` it returns a `binary!` of 34815 bytes (until STDIN is exhausted).  NB. In fact the `/lines` (and `/string`) don't do anything on MacOS :(

Answer (score 3):

I came across same problem with `input` a couple of years ago.  I don't think this is a planned change but rather an incomplete implementation (touch wood!).

Here is a workaround function i wrote at that time (which has worked fine for me on MacOS & Linux).

```
input-line: function [
    {Return next line (string!) from STDIN.  Returns NONE when nothing left}
    /part size [integer!] "Internal read/part (buffer) size"
  ][
    buffer: {}    ;; static
    if none? part [size: 1024]

    forever [
        if f: find buffer newline [
            remove f    ;; chomp newline (NB. doesn't cover Windows CRLF?)
            break
        ]

        if empty? data: read/part system/ports/input size [
            f: length? buffer
            break
        ]

        append buffer to-string data
    ]

    unless all [empty? data empty? buffer] [take/part buffer f]
]
```

Usage example:

```
while [not none? line: input-line] [
    ;; do something with LINE of data from STDIN
]
```